# TranslateZ is broken in Firefox56

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

Here I collected a bunch of examples where there are two boxes: one is red and the other is blue. Red should always be in front of the blue.

1. **Absolute positioned blocks, on top of each other:** doesn't work.
2. **Absolute positioned blocks, red offset from blue:** it does work!
3. **Absolute positioned blocks, red offset from blue and has some text:** doesn't work.
4. **Absolute positioned blocks, red offset from blue and has some text, parent rotated:** does work!

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 75px;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    margin: 15px;
}

.rotated {
  transform:rotateY(30deg) rotateX(-30deg);
}

.red,
.blue {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

.red {
    background: red;
    transform: translateZ(30px);
}

.blue {
    background: royalblue;
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}

.moved {
    left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!-- On top of each other -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
<!-- red moved by non-0 value -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="red moved"></div>
    <div class="blue">Text here doesn't matter</div>
</div>
<!-- text -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="red moved">Text here breaks everything</div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
<!-- rotation -->
<div class="container rotated">
    <div class="red moved">Text here is ok</div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Here is how it looks like in Firefox56: [image: How I see it] 
 Examples 1 and 3 are broken. Red should always be in front of blue.

---

In Chrome the four examples render properly (as in Firefox57 and 59alpha). In Firefox56 (and many others, I guess) they don't. Is it a solvable Firefox problem?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? When I look at your demo the second and third examples look the same (with the exception that the text is inside a different div), but you say that one example works while the other doesn't. Also can you describe what you expect to see? Unless you rotate or apply perspective to elements then I wouldn't expect translateZ to have a visible affect.

Comment: Oh! That's strange. By the way, in the second example the red box is in front of the blue one, whilst on the third one is the opposite (even if the red box box should always be aboce the blue one). According to my understanding, translateZ should have tangible effects when parent has `transform-style: preserve-3d`, shouldn't it? I will edit the question with additional information and screenshot

Comment: @fedeTibaldo The red box is in front in all 4 examples in Chrome

Comment: Added screenshot and updated question. The way Chrome handles the rendering is just another proof that something is broken inside of Firefox (at least). It's sad to have inconsistent behaviours with such a fundamental property! Is there something I can do to fix it?

Comment: In Firefox 57 (and 59alpha), it looks the same as in Chrome. Probably some issue in older FF versions.

Comment: Thank you @helb, I updated the question with additional version numbers. Many users still use older Firefox versions (like me, ouch), so it would be nice to find a way to make it work!

Comment: Firefox 52.5.0 works too, probably has the fix backported. With `z-index: 1` on `.red`, it works even in FF 56, but i don't like this workaround…

Comment: Thanks again for your help @helb. I'll delete this question in a few hours, since it's more about a version-specific bug/different interpretation than a real programming issue. I don't like that workaround either, so I'll leave out Firefox 56. It's not my fault if it doesn't work as it should